# FirebaseUI InflateException, Error inflating class TextView

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I'm trying to sign in with Firebase Auth. When I open the app, I recieve the following error:

```
03-09 16:25:02.532 20054-20054/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger, PID: 20054
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger/com.firebase.ui.auth.KickoffActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class TextView
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3003)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3064)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1659)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class TextView
                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class TextView
                                                Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040077 a=4 r=0x7f06002c}
                                                   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:545)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1137)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1038)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:75)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:383)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:323)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onPostCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:170)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:97)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPostCreate(Instrumentation.java:1207)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2975)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3064)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1659)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
```

I've looked through a number of S/O posts haven't seemed to find something that'll work. Is there an easy fix for this or should I just remove the FirebaseUI dependency and make my own login screen?

Comment: Please add your layout file. it has some issue

Comment: The layout is generated by the FirebaseUI library (open source). I went to the KickoffActivity listed in the error message. I can not find a reference to a layout. https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/0e5bb59573e096b6bd5f0c951d367fed510ad949/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/KickoffActivity.java

Comment: your activity layout file has some issue. at the line #29 which is a textview. I will have to look at the tag content for the issue.

Comment: Please add you activity file code where you are defining the TextView.

Comment: @AlexMamo thats the thing, I don't know how to find the file because I didn't right it myself. It was generated from the FirebaseUI library. I looked the code for the activity mentioned in the error message and I cant find a reference to the layout in the java file. Check the url in my last comment to see for yourself.

Comment: the error is on line 29 in xml according to the error message. I tried moving around the elements in the xml docs for the layout. each time the app failed, but the line number didn't change, why?